# Minimizing rounding errors in square root of fraction

Tags: floating-point

In R I have

```
options(digits=22)
sqrt((1-exp(-20)))/sqrt((1-exp(-19.9)))
> 1.000000000108386855047
sqrt((1-exp(-20))/(1-exp(-19.9)))
> 1.000000000108386633002
```

My question is: can I expect one version to be more precise than the other, (also in other languages), or is it dependent on the implementation of division and `sqrt`?

Comment: The precision of a fixed-width floating-point format is fixed. You want better accuracy. `sqrt(a/b)` will tend to be more accurate than `sqrt(a)/sqrt(b)`, although rounding errors can act similarly to a random distribution, so one or the other may be more accurate with particular values. However, your bigger problem is calculating `1-exp(-x)`, which has (potentially and often) large relative error for large `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your second expression is wrong. It should be
`sqrt((1-exp(-10))/(1-exp(-9)))`, you computed the square root of a value like  `1-a/(1-b)` instead of
`(1-a)/(1-b`).

With this change both results are `1.000039008990497`.

---

Here is the updated answer: Computing `sqrt(1-x)` is a bit more inaccurate for small x. To get a slightly better result you can approximate with a Taylor series `sqrt(1-x) ~ 1 - x/2` (or higher terms, dependent on the value of x).

```
> x = exp(-20)
> y = exp(-19.9)
> sqrt((1-x)/(1-y))
[1] 1.0000000001083866
> sqrt(1-x)/sqrt(1-y)
[1] 1.0000000001083869
> (1-x/2)/(1-y/2)
[1] 1.0000000001083866
```

The correct rounded value is `1.0000000001083867`. You can see that the Taylor series value is the same as the first. IMO the differences are very small and normally not worth using the Taylor series.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my very bad and misleading example. But the question remains (see updated example).

Comment: @citronrose: Update the answer for your new example.